# Где происходит рендер сайта?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, клиент и сервер написан на js ( Keystone.js ) как узнать где рендерится код? И что увидят поисковые системы? На данный момент сайт находиться локально на компьютере.

Comment: Выключите js в браузере и зайдите на ваш сайт - получите представление о том, что видят поисковики. Гугл правда умеет работать с js, но не в полном объёме.

Comment: В посте появляется Очевидная Утка и говорит что окончательно код рендерится в браузере. Потому что где еще. Если вы преформируете какой-то кусок html на сервере, то очевидно он должен летать по сети в теле http запроса, и это тело можно посмотреть отладочными инструментами.